# Applying Function Using Different Columns - R

Tags: arrays, r, vector

I have an array in r that has thousands of rows and three different columns.  For each row in the array, I want to change the first column based on the first column and third column.  Specifically, if the number in the third column is larger than the number in the first column, it should return a 1, if the number in the third column is smaller than the number in the first column, it should return a 0, if they are the same number it should randomly choose 1 or 0.

```
    temp[,1]<- sapply(
                        temp[,1],
                        function(score){
                           if(temp[,3]>score){1}
                           else if(temp[,3]<score){0}else
                           else if(temp[,3]==score){sample(0:1,1)}})
```

This is the code I have so far but it isn't quite working, I think when I call "temp[,3]" it returns a vector with all the rows in the third column, I just want the one entry in that row corresponding to the row I get with "score".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ifelse`:

```
ifelse(temp[,1] < temp[,3], 1, # test condition 1, give 1 if TRUE
       ifelse(temp[,1] > temp[,3], 0, # condition 1 is FALSE, test condition 2
              rbinom(dim(temp)[1],1,.5))) # condition 2 is FALSE, return random
```

*EDIT*: `ifelse` works by testing a condition, then doing something if that condition is `TRUE` or something else if it is `FALSE`. You have three conditions, so instead of providing a value for when the first condition (`temp[,1] < temp[,3]`) is `FALSE`, this provides a second `ifelse` statement, which tests your second condition `(temp[,1] > temp[,3])`.

All remaining cases are then generated randomly using `rbinom`. This has to be a vector rather than draw because otherwise all of your rows that do not meet conditions 1 and 2 would be given the same random draw. If you try:

```
ifelse(temp[,1]<temp[,3],1,ifelse(temp[,1]>temp[,3],0,rbinom(1,1,.5)))
```

You'll see that all rows where `temp[,1]==temp[,3]` have the same value. It would be the same as just doing something like:

```
ifelse(temp[,1]<temp[,3],1,ifelse(temp[,1]>temp[,3],0,2))
```

Comment: thomas i just tried this code it works perfect.  could you please explain why the second ifelse is embedded inside of the first ifelse? and why do you do rbinom(dim(temp)[1]) which i think means you are getting random numbers for each row i have?

Comment: Updated with some additional explanation.

Comment: ah i see.  i am coming from python i use to solve this stuff by looping through a list.  i like the way r works with vectors more.  answer accepted

Answer (score 4):

This can also be done using arithmetic instead of conditionals:

```
rbinom(nrow(temp), 1, (temp[,1]<temp[,3])+(temp[,1]==temp[,3])*0.5)
```